# How many questions can be asked by one person

Tags: discussion, questions

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu
Please I want to ask that how many question can I ask in the main site?

Comment: I don't think so there is a limit to that. If not spamming and they are questions that are helpful to the Islamic community, then there should be no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say ask as much as you like, but avoid question duplicates. If there should be any limitation it can only be a daily limit or a limit for new users or such.

Comment: Maybe new users should receive a limit, like a daily cap until they reach a certain reputation level. This way we can prevent unnecessary spam just in case.

Comment: @NanoAdam that wouldn't hinder some, as they may create new accounts and go on spamming.